# Readability in nested conditional statements

Tags: python, conditional-statements, code-readability

I'm currently writing a program in Python to model projective geometry, and the congruence function for a projective point is looking rather nasty.

(for anyone interested, two projective points are congruent if they both lie on a single line passing through the origin.)

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.coords = [ a, b, c ]

    def congruent(self, other):
        ratio = 0
        for i in range(3):
            if self.coords[i] != 0 and other.coords[i] != 0:
                if ratio is 0:
                    ratio = other.coords[i] / self.coords[i]
                elif ratio != other.coords[i] / self.coords[i]:
                    return False
            elif self.coords[i] != 0 or other.coords[i] != 0:
                return False
        return True
```

I'm new to Python, but I know that there's generally a "Pythonic" way to do everything.  With that in mind, how would I go about making this more readable?

Comment: Question about your code: you set `ratio = 0` but then check `if ratio is 0:`, is something missing?  Why would `ratio` be anything but 0?

Comment: This question seems to be subjective, discussion and opinion based... Doesn't really have an objective answer.

Comment: After the code checks ratio is 0, it assigns ratio to a new value.  After that happens, ratio should never be reassigned.

There's probably a better way to do that, though.

Comment: @Patrick, Set ratio using the 0 coords outside the loop, then start your loop at index 1 instead.  That will make it clearer that it isn't expected to change during the loop.

Comment: @PaulButcher that's what I was getting at.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be migrated to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @RobertH Closing questions help nothing for migration, if you feel that it should be migrated, click 'flag' -> in need of moderator intervention
-> say that you think it should be migrated.

Comment: @PaulButcher I was worried about division by zero, since the 0 coords aren't guaranteed to both be nonzero.

Comment: @Patrick Ok now I understand why you had that out there.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg not sure about flagging for mod intervention; they generally don't have time for this. See this [meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228626/for-questions-which-might-belong-on-maths-stats-etc-is-is-better-to-vote-to-c).

Comment: @RobertH yeah I guess it would have been better at CodeReview.  My bad.

Comment: @TooTone It surely can take a while for the flags to be handled, but I have good experience with flagging for migration. Although I have a high amount of reputation on CR, which makes moderators trust me more. In addition, RobertH's close reason did not specifically say that it is ***off-topic for Stack Overflow***, which makes it a horrible close-reason overall. "I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs at (other site)" is not a valid close reason. If you want to discuss more, you can find me in [2nd monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor)

Comment: @RobertH Being on-topic on another Stack Exchange site does not, by itself, make a question off-topic where it is posted.  See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228626/for-questions-which-might-belong-on-maths-stats-etc-is-is-better-to-vote-to-c) and [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287400/does-being-on-topic-at-another-stack-exchange-site-automatically-make-a-question). This question *may* be on-topic for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help), but the first criteria for question migration is that the question be off-topic on the source site.

Comment: @TooTone You can retract your close vote (though if you feel this question is off-topic for Stack Overflow, you shouldn't), but I'd recommend leaving a comment explaining to the asker why this question doesn't belong on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg et al: Closing was my opinion as I felt this style of question was better migrated - If you disagree, that's fine. May a flag been more appropriate? - Perhaps. Alas, I chose to cast a close vote and while I'm glad to have sparked discussion, I am sad that its detracted away from the question itself, which I do find a valuable contribution to the community, regardless of which site it rests on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
def congruent(self, other, eps=0.001):
    ratios = (c1 / c2 for c1, c2 in zip(self.coords, other.coords) if c1 or c2)
    try:
        first = next(ratios)
        return all(abs(ratio - first) < eps for ratio in ratios)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return False
```

1. Prefer operating directly over elements instead of on indices if possible (`zip` is handy).
2. The list comprehension gets all coord ratios for cases where *either* coordinate is non-zero. If both are, it's fine, and it gets excluded.
3. The ZDE only happens if `c1` is nonzero and `c2` is zero, so that's a fail.
4. At the end, we pass if all ratios are equal.

Note: If you're not using Python 3, you should add `from __future__ import division` to the top of your file so that you don't get incorrect results for integer coordinate values.

**Edit:** added short-circuiting and epsilon-comparison for float ratios per @JoranBeasley.

Comment: bah better than mine even. ... I feel like you could use some short circuiting with all and a generator ... but great answer +1

Comment: @JoranBeasley Yeah I thought about putting the `all` into the `try`, it's a simple substitution but it harms readability a bit.

Comment: `0.0/0.0` does give me a ZDE so not entirely sure that bit will work as expected but looks believe-able enough

Comment: @JoranBeasley added short-circuit, check it out :). If both are `0.0` then they'll get excluded from the ratio list since `if c1 or c2` is `False`.

Comment: `Point(1,1,1).congruent(Point(0,0,0))` returns False

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use `if self.coords[i]` instead of `if self.coords[i] != 0` (same for similar examples) and `if not ratio` instead of `if ratio is 0`. In Python, any nonzero value passes `if` clause, so you don't need to check if it is nonzero, it is automatic.

Answer (score 1):

```
def congurent(self,other):
    ratio = None
    for a,b in zip(self,other):
        if a != 0 and b != 0:
            if ratio is None: 
                 ratio = a/float(b)
            elif abs(ratio - a/float(b))>0.001:
                 return False
        elif a!=0 or b!=0:
            return False
     return True
```

is perhaps a little more pythonic... although all its really changing is how you iterate over the list (its the same number of lines)

Comment: Sweet.  Is `abs(ratio - a/float(b))>0.001` for float comparison?

Comment: yeah its hard to test equality with floats because of how they are :P